Dependency issue in generating Java classes from Avro schema using Apache avro's SpecificCompilerTool for java 21
I want to convert Java classes from avro schemas/avsc files and for that, I have tried to implement this solution of SpecificCompilerTool from Baeldung's article  & StackOverflow's answer but facing dependency issues.
Below is the exception at the time of 'gradle build' command. (executed 'gradle clean' before build which was successful, tried Invalidate cache & restart IDE too)
Exception:
2024-06-17T11:02:12.836+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2024-06-17T11:02:12.837+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2024-06-17T11:02:12.837+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2024-06-17T11:02:12.837+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
2024-06-17T11:02:12.837+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':bootJar'.
2024-06-17T11:02:12.837+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > 'void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream.putArchiveEntry(org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry)'
2024-06-17T11:02:12.837+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2024-06-17T11:02:12.838+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
2024-06-17T11:02:12.838+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
2024-06-17T11:02:12.838+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Run with --scan to get full insights.
2024-06-17T11:02:12.838+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
2024-06-17T11:02:12.839+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
2024-06-17T11:02:12.839+0530 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 15s

Unable to find method ''void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream.putArchiveEntry(org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry)''
'void org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveOutputStream.putArchiveEntry(org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry)'
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
build.gradle:
buildscript {
dependencies {
// Add the Avro code generation to the build dependencies so that it can be used in a Gradle task.
classpath group: 'org.apache.avro', name: 'avro-tools', version: '1.11.0'
    }
}

plugins {
id 'java'
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.0'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
id 'application'
id "org.sonarqube" version "5.0.0.4638"
id "jacoco"
}

group = 'com.sample'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21

repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven {
    url "https://packages.confluent.io/maven"
   }
maven {
    url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
   }
}

dependencies {

    //implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.20' // Downgrade commons-compress version
    
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    
    implementation ('org.apache.avro:avro:1.11.0') {
            //exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-compress'
    } // Exclude commons-compress from avro
    
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.register('avroCodeGeneration') {
    inputs.dir("src/main/resources/avro")
    outputs.dir("src/main/java/avro")
    doLast {
        new org.apache.avro.tool.SpecificCompilerTool().run(System.in, System.out, System.err, List.of(
            "-encoding", "UTF-8",
            "-string",
            "-fieldVisibility", "private",
            "-noSetters",
            "schema", "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/avro".toString(), "${projectDir}/src/main/java/avro".toString()
        ))
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
dependsOn('avroCodeGeneration')
}

tasks.named('test') {
useJUnitPlatform()
}

I was able to find, the org.apache.commons library present under 'External Libraries' section of IDE. Also, I was able to find class 'ZipArchiveOutputStream' & method 'putArchiveEntry' under that, which means dependency was downloaded.
But somehow, it's showing error: 'method not found' during BUILD.
When I remove, avro dependency, my project gets BUILD successfully. But then in the generated class, there are imports of org.apache.avro like,
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericArray;
import org.apache.avro.util.Utf8;

So, my code gives error on those lines, as it won't be able to find that dependency, as it's not present in build.gradle.
I tried, 'exclude compress' under avro depedency thinking it might be coming from both- avro & avro-tools, but it didn't work.
I've tried checking dependency tree and the 'avro compress' dependency is present under avro only. It is not a sub-depedency under any other dependencies.
I also added, 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.20' under dependencies, assuming it will override all other 'compress sub-dependency', if there are any, but getting same error.
I ain't sure, if it's because of some kind of ambiguity.
Please help. Thanks in advance.
IntelliJ IDE.
Gradle: 8.7
Java 21
Note: I cannot use, OpenSource lib, as it as ended support for java versions 19 and above.

I encountered a similar issue, likely due to a conflict between Spring Boot and Avro Tools.
Although I couldn't find a direct solution, here's the workaround that helped me:

Create a Library for the Generated Avro Classes:
In your library project, add the Avro Tools dependency:
compileOnly 'org.apache.avro:avro-tools:1.11.3'

Include the Library in Your Spring Boot Application:


After generating the Avro classes in the library, add this library as a dependency in your Spring Boot application.
This approach separates the Avro code generation from your main application, avoiding potential conflicts and making your build process cleaner.
